# Where does MacOS store remembered Wi-Fi Names?

Tags: network, wifi

My mac knows about 50-100 different Wi-Fi network names. I'd like to know where they are remembered, I can't find it. I've searched.

I understand that there is a GUI for editing this information, but it is horrible.  I want to know the file where the data are stored. The Apple user interface is horrible because you can't search or sort. I have more than 100 names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah. I finally found it. The file is `/Library//Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` and it's under the `KnownNetworks` key.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you already found a way but I wanted to teach you an easier way.

System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > Wi-Fi

Use the Plus and Minus button to add/remove networks.